# Where to start: Adding a Facebook like button for each page

Tags: php, facebook

I have a site where a user submit a quote, each quote is added in a list and has its own page once created. The URL for each quote looks like: http://example.com/quote-231

My Client wants each quote to have its own like button that is displayed on the main page and the quote page itself. Each quote has it's own id.

I've tried to read developer.facebook.com and I can't really understand how I would implement the like button for each page, can someone explain what I need to do/find out/read to get this working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coded this in ColdFusion, but it should be very easy for you to adapt for PHP. This allows you to customise the thumbnail and description for the "like" button's data and display.

Inside the `head` tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Make Model"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="somedetailpage.php/id/#youruniqueid#"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="#thumbnailimageurl#"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="#sitename#"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="#facebookadminuserid#"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="#somedetailpageshortdescription#"/>
```

Inside the `body` tag:

```
<fb:like href="somedetailpage.php/id/#youruniqueid#" layout="button_count" show-faces="false" width="90" height="20" />
```

Inside the `body` tag (at the end in the footer):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
</script>
```

Check out the Facebook docs for the different `og:type` options.

Hope that helps?

Comment: What would be somedetailpage.php/id/#youruniqueid#? the quote URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter something like this on your quote page template:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[URL]&send=false&layout=button_count" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 115px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

where [URL] is the url of your quote.

This is the iframe version. There is also a js one.

You can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. There you will find a code generator.

Comment: So just echo the id with php in the iframe? Is that all? Can't be that simple.

Comment: The iframe approach is the simplest one, and also, the one that has the smaller footprint. The XFBML option is more "complete" because it provides access to other tools from facebook, but adds some javascript that you might not want on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Create the code with this tool http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and then just set the current url on your output page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)? I prefer the JS implementation of the FB like functionality, so the following code snippets are based on XFBML.

After you register for a FB developer account, you can register your site, then you can make calls on your quote page akin to:

```
 // The script serving your quote content should have a method of retrieving 
 //  quote data.  It looks like you have some http rewrite rules in place for 
 //  pretty url, but you should still have access to the quote id
 //  something like
 $canonicalUrl = 'http://example.com/quote.php?id=' . $row['id']);

 <div class="yui3-u-1-2 facebookWrap">
     <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $canonicalUrl ?>" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
 </div>
```

And to include the necessary JS to make your like buttons work (this should be at the bottom of your pages):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
         appId      : 'your_app_id', // App ID
         channelURL : '//yourhost.com/channel.html', // Channel File
         status     : true, // check login status
         cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
         xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
     });

 // Additional initialization code here
 };

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));</script>
```

The settings above can be edited to suit your needs, but should get you started.

Comment: So in my case, it would be:  $canonicalUrl = 'http://example.com/quote-3211'; where 3211 is the id and I get the id with PHP?  $canonicalUrl = 'http://yourhost.com/quote.php/?quoteId=' . <?php echo id ?>;? I'm new to this so I don't really know if I am correct.

Comment: Updated the comments of above the $canonicalUrl construct which should answer your question.

Comment: Can you explain what method I would use to get the id of each quote? Here is how each quote is displayed: http://pastie.org/private/mdpmlzw1tg6lprln5txw

Comment: You can do a `var_dump($row)` to see the associative keys available in the array, but chances are `$row['id']` should work. Updated posted using `$row['id']`.

Comment: where exactly can I register for a  FB developer account?

Comment: Facebook adheres to the single account per person design. According to this blog post (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/386), you can  flag your Facebook account as a developer account. What I would recommend doing is creating a company Facebook account for your client, confirm it as a developer account, then add your personal Facebook account as a confirmed contributor.